# How to start systemctl service with different env vars / diff arguments?

Tags: systemd, systemctl

Say I have a service definition like:

```
[Unit]
Description=ES log capture
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Environment=emit_only_json=yes
Environment=ec2_logging_machine_ip=ec2-18-xxx-66-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=root
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/repos/es-app/syslog-exec.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

but I want the `ec2_logging_machine_ip` env var to differ depending on which machine this service runs on. Here is the bash script that the service runs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -eo pipefail
cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")"

export interos_emit_only_json='nope'
export interos_ec2_logging_machine_ip='ec2-18-xxx-66-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com'

tail -n 100 -f '/var/log/syslog' | node . &> /dev/null
```

I can also put env vars in there. Maybe the answer is to alter the `.bashrc` for this machine? Any other potential solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Altering ~/.bashrc and then source'ing it in my ExecStart script didn't work, but using this did work:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/home/ubuntu/myenvs/es-service.env
```